# Why is it required to know the function selector in a smart contract to call the function?

Tags: contract-design, contract-invocation, evm, abi, bytecode

I understand what a function selector is and how it is [computed](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/abi-spec.html):

> The first four bytes of the call data for a function call specifies
>   the function to be called. It is the first (left, high-order in
>   big-endian) four bytes of the Keccak-256 (SHA-3) hash of the signature
>   of the function.

However, I fail to see why knowing the selector is important as far as calling the function is concerned. For a loadable dynamic library (`.so` on Linux, `.dll` on Windows), a list of callable symbols are imported which serves as the entry points to external clients. Isn't there anything like that in EVM bytecode? If not, how does the EVM locate the method given the function selector? Don't the functions exist as separate entities in the compiled bytecode?

Comment: Welcome to the Ethereum Stack Exchange! Functions do not exist as separate entities in the compiled EVM bytecode. This may be a duplicate of some other ABI related questions, please check them out, and if not duplicate, feel free to reopen or edit. Thanks

Comment: tldr: functions names aren't stored in compiled evm bytecode. a solidity compilter turns your function "signature" (function name, plug argument types in order) into a selector (by hashing that signature and taking the first four bytes), and treats _that signature_ as the function name within the bytecode. So, to call that function, you have to have the selector, because the selector is all that is stored on the blockchain.